# TortoiseSVN and renaming author

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, local, author

I working on a company machine and cannot change the name of the windows username. I am running TortoiseSvn locally and I would like to change the commits to my name. I do not want to right click each commit and manually change the names. Is there a way to do this? I know that there are a couple of threads about this but there are no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to do it, but you probably can't.

In Subversion, there are two types of properties: File properties that are revisioned with the file itself, and Revision properties that are attached not to a file, but to a revision. These are not versioned.

There are several standard revision properties:

- **svn:log**: This is the commit comment.
- **svn:author**: This is the user who made the commit.
- **svn:date**: This is the date and time stamp of the commit.

You can change any of these revision properties with this command:

```
$ svn pset svn:log --rev-prop -r193 "The commit comment for revsion #193 is this!"
```

It would be fairly simple to write a script in PowerShell or Python or Perl to do this to a whole bunch of revisions at once. However, you can imagine what type of havoc this could wreck if you could change the date, authorship, and commit comment of any Subversion revision at whim.

Therefore, in order to be able to use a `rev-prop` change, the repository must have a hook to allow you to do this. This is the only case where you must have a hook to explicitly allow a permitted action. And, of course, it is highly doubtful that you will have the ability to create such a hook.

---

Now, I'm assuming you were talking about already committed revisions. If you are sharing a working copy, and you make changes, and then commit those changes along with everyone else, you're using Subversion all wrong.

Each user should have their own working directory where they can make changes. This way, the repository will record who did the commit without any shenanigans.

---

If you simply want to checkout from the repository with a name other than your Windows name, you can save your authentication on your local machine, and Subversion will use that authorization when it does checkouts from that repository.

I believe that authorizations are stored under the %HOMEPATH%.subversion\auth directory. It shouldn't take too long to find the file with the authorization and delete it. Then, when you checkout the next time, you need to specify the user and password and save the credentials. After that, that's what TortoiseSVN will use by default when you use that repository.

---

That's three different answers covering three different situations in using Subversion and credentials. If I didn't answer the correct scenario, edit your question and explain exactly what you mean and what you want to accomplish. The situation you describe isn't very clear.